# openpyxl - how to put value with a leading single quote

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In Excel, single quote prefix is used to designate that value is a text and should not be converted to any other type.
Normally, single quote is not displayed when viewing a workbook (but it is visible when editing cell content).

Is it possible to put such value in a cell, using openpyxl? I have found no way to do it.

Here is sample code

```
import openpyxl
import os
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
sheet.cell("A1", value="'value")
sheet.cell("B1").value = "'value"
sheet.cell("C1").set_explicit_value("'value", 's')
outpath = r"d:\dmishin\temp\wb.xlsx" #put your path here
wb.save(outpath)
os.startfile(outpath)
```

This code creates a worksheet with 3 cells, putting 'value to them. I expect to see the text without leading quote when viewing it, but instead I see this:

[image: Visible leading quote]

Manual editing creates this (note that quote is still displayed when editing)

[image: No leading quote visible]

After comparing XLSX files contents manually, I have an impression that the information about the quote is stored in the cell style tag, quotePrefix attribute.

In openpyxl sources, CellStyle class has corresponding boolean field quotePrefix. However, I see no way to manually set this field. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try `sheet.cell("C1").set_explicit_value("value", 's')`

Comment: `set_explicit_value` seems to work for me, as long as you don't actually *need* the single-quote/apostrophe in the cell. If you expect to "see" the value without the leading quote, do you actually need the leading quote mark?

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes. You line puts text "value" to the cell, that has no leading quote neither when viewing cell, nor when editing it.
It is not what I need.
Setting cell.number_format = FORMAT_TEXT also does not add quote.

Comment: @DavidZemens, sure, but I actually *need* the quote, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: As I understand Excel, the single-quote is not actually a part of the cell's value. If you require it to be part of the cell's value, then it will always be visible. If you want it to be functionally equivalent to the "number stored as text" flag, then that can be done with the `set_explicit_value` method, but you'll lose the character (which isn't part of the cell value, anyways).

Comment: @DavidZemens, it is a bit embarassing to tell exact details. Long story short, it is written in my bug ticket. Particularly, cell with no text behaves a bit different from cell with a sole ' (quoted empty string).

I know a way to achieve required behavior without tricks with quote (and it is probably cleaner and better), but the change is bigger.

Comment: haven't tried it yet, but are you bound to openpyxl or could you have better results maybe using xlrd/xlwt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to change `quotePrefix` attribute on a cell, but if you *really* need to have `quotePrefix` set to `True`, you can update the cell's `_style` attribute which has a style_array (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.cell_style.html#openpyxl.styles.cell_style.StyleArray) `array('i', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` so that the 8th value (which should correspond to quotePrefix) is 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code example how to put in a cell value with a leading single quote:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlFilePath = "testquote.xlsx" #put your path here

wb = load_workbook(filename=xlFilePath)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
_cell = ws.cell(1, 1)
_cell.quotePrefix = 1
_cell.value = "your_value"

wb.save(xlFilePath)
```

In the cell "A1" you get the value with a leading single quote: 'your_value.

What is more, single quote is not displayed when viewing a workbook (but it is visible when editing cell content).

Comment: Can you add more explanation in the answer.

Comment: @v.coder The answer has been edited. So more clear?

Comment: What if we want to remove the quote can `cell.quotePrefix` set to 0

Answer (score -3):

In Excel you use the single quote to stop Excel converting a numerical string into a number. In openpyxl you don't need to this, just assign the cell the value as a string, eg. `ws['A1'] = "4"`.

openpyxl does not support the `quotePrefix` attribute.

Comment: That's not the only scenario. Something like "=ABC" will still cause an issue.